# how to check if an html element has certain text with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an html p tag as showen below

```html
   <p class="card-about-bambo-number card-aboot-mahagany-number">0 <spam>left</spam></p>
```

I also have a button that I would like to be disabled when the p tag has a 0 in.

I have tried doing this both within JavaScript and jquery.

I tried using includes but this didnt work, I have also tried using contains.

Here is the code I have tired

```js
$(document).ready(() => {


  if ($(".card-about-mahagany-number:contains('0')")) {
    $('.btn-about-mahagany').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('.card-about-mahagany-body').addClass('card-zero');
  }

});

const numberText = document.getElementsByClassName('card-aboot-mahagany-number');
const buttonOut = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-about-mahagany');
//buttonOut.disabled = true;

if (numberText.textContent.includes('0')) {
  buttonOut.disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<p class="card-about-bambo-number card-aboot-mahagany-number">0 <spam>left</spam></p> 
   
    <button class="btn btn-select btn-about-mahagany btn-primary" disabled="false">Out of Stock</button>
```

Comment: You have a typo: `comtains` should be `contains`

Comment: jQuery objects are always truthy. If you want to know if the element exists, get the length: `if ($('selector').length > 0)`

Comment: doesn't fix the problem

Comment: `numberText` is a list of elements, not a single element. You need to index it or loop over it.

Comment: Tip: use plural variable names for collections (and similar) types, so you know if you have a single or multiple:  `const numberText = document.getElementsByClassName('card-aboot-mahagany-number');`  then `numberTexts.textContent` should be clear that it makes no sense

Comment: So many typos.  `card-about-mahagany-number` doesn't match with `card-aboot-mahagany-number` - test your selectors by breaking them down.  Your [code works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/h0meq5La/) without the cheesy typos

Comment: sorry think I copyed the wrong part of my code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

document.getElementsByClassName returns an array-like object of the elements with that class.

Try this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < numberText.length; i++) {
  if (numberText[i].textContent.includes("0")) {
    for (let i = 0; i < buttonOut.length; i++) {
      buttonOut[i].disabled = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: nope doesn't work

Comment: then there's something else wrong with your code like a typo, because this would work

Comment: nope I have checked and it disabled the button but if I can the 0 within the p tag to 4 the button is still disabled

Comment: That's because you are changing a different HTML element. Not the one you select with the getElementsByClassName.

Comment: If you want to account for the span tag you need to specify that.

Comment: even without the span tag it still does the same thing

Comment: Post your code to codesandbox or codepen

Comment: https://codepen.io/rebekahshaw92/pen/xxpyPeJ

Comment: I fixed it myself, i needed to take out the disabled on the button

Answer (score -1):

First, lets change from `<spam>` to `<span>`.

Second, we try to create a simple code for one card only.
In this case, if you change the value from 0 to 1, you will see the button.
If you change the value from 1 to 0, the button will not show up when you run it.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  console.log('document ready');
  
  let card = $('p.card-about-bambo-number');
    
  console.log(card.text());
  
  let value = +card.text().replace(/\D+/g, "");
  console.log('value: ', value);
  console.log('value type: ', typeof(value));
  
  $('#btn').toggle(value > 0);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="card-about-bambo-number card-aboot-mahagany-number">0 <span>left</span></p>
<button id="btn">Button</button>
```

Third, lets modify this to work with more than one card:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
      
      let cards = $('p.card-about-bambo-number');
      
      cards.each(function() {
        let card = $(this);
        
        let value = +card.text().replace(/\D+/g, "");
        
        card.next('#btn').toggle(value > 0);
      });
        
      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="card-about-bambo-number card-aboot-mahagany-number">0 <span>left</span></p>
<button id="btn">Button</button>

<hr/>

<p class="card-about-bambo-number card-aboot-mahagany-number">1 <span>left</span></p>
<button id="btn">Button</button>
```

Using the class `card-about-bambo-number`, we will iterate throughout all the elements that have that class.

For each card, we will use the method `text` to extract the text, then we use regular expression to remove anything that isn't a digit, next we convert the number from a string to a number using `+` in front (a "javascript hack"), and with that we obtain the number.

Finally, we indicate that with want the next sibling to that element containing such class, to toggle (show/hide) depending if the value is higher than zero.

I hope this helps out.

Comment: It would be great to have an explanation behind the negative vote.

Answer (score -2):

textcontent should be innerHTML

Comment: now I'm getting an error Uncaught TypeError: numberText.innerHTML is undefined

Comment: *textcontent should be innerHTML* - why?   If you use innerHTML then it will include html, and OP hasn't made it clear if that's relevant, eg search for "test" in `te<i>s</i>t` and it will find it in textcontent but not in innerHTML.